# Backpropagation on Two Layered Networks

Tags: deep-learning, backpropagation

i have been following cs231n lectures of Stanford and trying to complete assignments on my own and sharing these solutions both on github and my blog. But i'm having a hard time on understanding how to modelize backpropagation. I mean i can code modular forward and backward passes but what bothers me is that if i have the model below : [Two Layered Neural Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWIyV.png)

Lets assume that our loss function here is a softmax loss function. In my modular softmax_loss() function i am calculating loss and gradient with respect to scores (dSoft = dL/dY). After that, when i'am following backwards lets say for b2, db2 would be equal to dSoft*1 or dW2 would be equal to dSoft*dX2(outputs of relu gate). What's the chain rule here ? Why isnt dSoft equal to 1 ? Because dL/dL would be 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

The softmax function is outputs a number given an input x. 
What dSoft means is that you're computing the derivative of the function softmax(x) with respect to the input x. Then to calculate the derivative with respect to W of the last layer you use the chain rule i.e. dL/dW = dsoftmax/dx * dx/dW. Note that x = W*x_prev + b where x_prev is the input to the last node. Therefore dx/dW is just x and dx/db is just 1, which means that dL/dW or simply dW is dsoftmax/dx * x_prev and dL/db or simply db is dsoftmax/dx * 1. Note that here dsoftmax/dx is dSoft we defined earlier.